# Idiomatic retry loop in Go

Tags: go

I recently started taking on the [Gossip Glomers distributed systems challanges](https://fly.io/dist-sys/) as a way for me to practice writing Go and learn something new. In order to solve one of the challenges, I had a request being delegated to a goroutine, which in turn retries sending the request at regular intervals until a response is received, as follows

```
func withTimeout(t time.Duration, f func(ctx context.Context) (maelstrom.Message, error)) (maelstrom.Message, error) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), t)
    defer cancel()
    return f(ctx)
}

func (b *broadcaster) gossip(messages []float64, neighbor string) {
    body := broadcastMessage{Type: "broadcast", Messages: messages}
    for {
        msg, err := withTimeout(b.config.gossipTimeout, func(ctx context.Context) (maelstrom.Message, error) {
            return b.node.SyncRPC(ctx, neighbor, body)
        })
        if err == nil {
            if err := json.Unmarshal(msg.Body, &body); err != nil {
                log.Fatalln(err)
            }
            if body.Type != "broadcast_ok" {
                log.Fatalln("unexpected response type", body.Type)
            }
            break
        }
    }
}
```

This code can be found [here](https://github.com/stefanobaghino/gossip-glomers/blob/374762ef8ebd56794fd4bfd81987360681e97e56/03-broadcast/main.go#L177-L193) in the context of the overall solution (~200 SLOC).

What I'm not 100% convinced by is the way I deal with the retry in a loop: I have an infinite loop, and I explicitly break out of it if `err == nil`, otherwise I keep on going. The reason why this smells a bit to me, is because I usually saw error handling trying to look for `err != nil` and acting on that instead.

I used to have a check for `err != nil`, in which case I `continue`d, otherwise I went through what is now in the body of the `if`, but this meant that I had to both `continue` *and* `break` explicitly, which can become unwieldy if you have logic which is more complex than this.

Another approach I tried to take was to have the call to `b.node.SyncRPC` as the init and post statements in the `for`, but that still required me to manually deal with breaking out of the loop from within it (and on top of that, specifying that twice seems once again like it makes this less readable).

Is there an established, succinct and readable idiom to deal with retries in a loop like the one in the code above?

One thing that might make this more readable is to use recursion instead and add the retry behind an `if`, but I'm not sure of whether Go supports tail-call optimization, in which case I would probably prefer to stick to a `for` loop in this case.

Answer (score 2):

(Disclaimer: I am not a gopher. But I am a software engineer.)

I didn't feel there was anything so terrible about
your "while true ... break", so I didn't see any constructive
criticism to offer about the OP code.
But the new code I feel could be improved.

---

## DRY

```
    msg, err :=       b.syncRPCWithTimeout(dest, broadcast)
    for err != nil {
        msg, err =    b.syncRPCWithTimeout(dest, broadcast)
    }
```

The [duplicate call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)
seems painful.

Here we're calling with a small list of very simple
side-effect free expressions.
But across a project that won't always be so.
I discourage adopting such a copy-n-paste habit.

Better to "prime the pump" by initializing `err` to non-nil, or
[defining](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32844744) a boolean, IMHO.
Then, within the loop, a single call suffices.

Answer (score 2):

I like the code in your answer. There are some ways to make it more DRY, as recommended, but it's also a one-liner. I agree with [@J_H](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/286871/277217) that it's not a great habit to copy/paste like this often. Here's one way to address that feedback.

```golang
var (
    shouldRetry = true
    msg maelstrom.Message
    err error
)
for shouldRetry {
    msg, err = b.syncRPCWithTimeout(dest, broadcast)
    if err == nil {
        shouldRetry = false
    }
}
```

It might be that I haven't really dug into the constraints of what you're trying to accomplish, but unbound retries make me nervous in general. If there's a timeout that you could apply to the whole retry loop, or a higher level context you could use for cancellation, I'd recommend passing that in. Otherwise, you could find yourself in a livelock situation retrying one (seemingly synchronous) operation forever.

In concrete terms, making `gossip` accept a context would likely be an improvement, and this would give `syncRPCWithTimeout` something other than `context.Background()` to base its own context on.

```golang
func (b *broadcaster) syncRPCWithTimeout(parent context.Context, dest string, req any) (maelstrom.Message, error) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(parent, b.config.gossipTimeout)
    defer cancel()
    return b.node.SyncRPC(ctx, dest, req)
}

func (b *broadcaster) gossip(parent context.Context, dest string, broadcast broadcastMessage) {
    msg, err := b.syncRPCWithTimeout(parent, dest, broadcast)
    for err != nil {
        select {
            case <-parent.Done():
                return
            default:
                // This branch will execute while the context hasn't been cancelled.
                msg, err = b.syncRPCWithTimeout(parent, dest, broadcast)
        }
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

With this code you could handle any event that results in this code needing to be cancelled, without this code actually needing to handle any specific situation. It just needs to watch for cancellation.

Additionally, I'd recommend - at the very least - logging errors that are received. If the error returned from `SyncRPC` is never reported, it would be really hard to figure out what's going on when this fails in production, as all code does at some point. I think the ideal case would be returning the error up the call stack to something that can handle it. In that case you could return `parent.Err()` inside the select case when the context is cancelled.

Lastly, `fmt.Fatalln` results in a call to `os.Exit`, which is a ***hard*** stop. No defers will be run, just a full stop. I almost always recommend returning an error over something that results in a call to `os.Exit`, because it allows you to collect and report more information for troubleshooting bugs in this or other systems.

Answer (score 1):

After some thinking I ended up with the following, which I'm relatively happy with:

```
func (b *broadcaster) syncRPCWithTimeout(dest string, req any) (maelstrom.Message, error) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), b.config.gossipTimeout)
    defer cancel()
    return b.node.SyncRPC(ctx, dest, req)
}

func (b *broadcaster) gossip(dest string, broadcast broadcastMessage) {
    msg, err := b.syncRPCWithTimeout(dest, broadcast)
    for err != nil {
        msg, err = b.syncRPCWithTimeout(dest, broadcast)
    }
    var body typeMessage
    if err := json.Unmarshal(msg.Body, &body); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    if body.Type != "broadcast_ok" {
        log.Fatalln("unexpected response type", body.Type)
    }
}
```

The retry code is repeated twice, but I would say for a good reason (as long as there's an error, keep retrying). I'm checking on `err != nil` which seems to be the more widely adopted way to check with errors. There's no manual tinkering with the looping condition.

I also made the function wrapping the synchronous RPC with a timeout a bit more concrete, since I don't need to reuse it.

I'm quite happy with this (although I just noticed I'll need to introduce a bit of nuance to deal with different errors), but I'd be happy to hear more from other, more experienced Go developers.